# Can't translate sentence from english to dutch

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I'm trying to translate a sentence from English to Dutch in the checkout page, but I have no idea how. [checkout screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvP61.jpg)

Comment: you can either go to that file and manually replace it. Or you will have to edit the .po file and add translation for the specific string.

Comment: Well, the problem is that there seems to be no file where i can edit this sentence.

Comment: you will have to search it in the plugin files that you are using. this requires a bit of programming knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

```
function woocommerce_login_form($args = array()) {

        $args = array(
            'message' => __('If you have shopped with us before, please enter your details below. If you are a new customer, please proceed to the Billing &amp; Shipping section.', 'woocommerce'),
            'redirect' => wc_get_page_permalink('checkout'),
            'hidden' => true,
        );

        wc_get_template('global/form-login.php', $args);
    }
```

Modify the text as you need and paste this function to your active theme functions.php